# Getting Selendroid standalone to run, Command 'aapt' was not found inside the Android SDK

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-sdk-tools, selendroid

I have been trying to work on things using selendroid, but I can't get the standalone to run.  I have been trying to run the command "java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.15.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.14.0.apk".  But I just keep getting "SEVERE: Error building server: Command 'aapt' was not found inside the Android SDK....".  I already referenced [This](https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/issues/538/), but it didn't help.

Paths to Java and Android SDK's
[image: Path to Java and Android SDK's]

Outputs in the Command Prompt 
[image: cmd line outputs]

I realized that the picture was a bit small...

```
    Apr 30, 2015 1:40:41 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: ################# Selendroid #################
Apr 30, 2015 1:40:41 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: ################# Configuration in use #################
Apr 30, 2015 1:40:41 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidConfiguration@816f27d[
  port=4444
  timeoutEmulatorStart=300000
  supportedApps=[selendroid-test-app-0.15.0.apk]
  verbose=false
  emulatorPort=5560
  deviceScreenshot=false
  selendroidServerPort=8080
  keystore=<null>
  keystorePassword=<null>
  keystoreAlias=<null>
  emulatorOptions=<null>
  keepEmulator=false
  registrationUrl=<null>
  proxy=<null>
  serverHost=<null>
  keepAdbAlive=false
  maxSession=5
  maxInstances=5
  noWebViewApp=false
  noClearData=false
  sessionTimeoutSeconds=1800
  forceReinstall=false
  logLevel=ERROR
  deviceLog=true
  serverStartTimeout=20000
  printHelp=false
  serverStartRetries=5
  folder=<null>
]
Apr 30, 2015 1:40:41 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
INFO: Starting Selendroid standalone on port 4444
Apr 30, 2015 1:40:41 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
SEVERE: Error building server: Command 'aapt' was not found inside the Android SDK. Please update to the latest development tools and try again.
```

If I left out any information just let me know.

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the latest 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-skd
```

Please try to change to:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

**EDIT:** Also check that `aapt.exe` is inside of `platform-tools` folder, otherwise copy `aapt.exe` from the last build tools you have, for example:

```
<android-sdk>\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe
```

to:

```
<android-sdk>\platform-tools\aapt.exe
```

Comment: Okay, I changed that, still get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Mattai said, Selendroid checks for aapt inside platform-tools.
But I was getting the same error even after copying the appt to platform-tools folder.
But worked when I tried after restarting the system!
Thanks Mattai!